# ListView prevent auto scroll on item tapped?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Trying to figure out if I can disable the auto scroll that occurs when a user taps on a cell in a `ListView` (I'm using a Recycle List View if it matters). I'm already setting the `sender.SelectedItem` to null to disable the cell highlight.

```
gridList.ItemSelected += (s, e) => {                    
      ((Xamarin.Forms.ListView)s).SelectedItem = null;        
};
```

**UPDATE** ItemTemplate Layout

```
            headline = new Xamarin.Forms.Label();
            cellImage = new Xamarin.Forms.Image();
            LoadingText = new Xamarin.Forms.Label();
            LoadingText.Text = "Loading...";
            layout = new Xamarin.Forms.Grid();
            layout.RowDefinitions.Add(new Xamarin.Forms.RowDefinition { Height = new Xamarin.Forms.GridLength(1, Xamarin.Forms.GridUnitType.Star) });
            layout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new Xamarin.Forms.ColumnDefinition { Width = new Xamarin.Forms.GridLength(1, Xamarin.Forms.GridUnitType.Star) });
            layout.Children.Add(LoadingText, 0, 0);
            layout.Children.Add(headline, 0, 0);
            layout.Children.Add(cellImage, 0, 0);
            layout.Children.Add(activityIndicator, 0, 0);

            LoadingText.HorizontalOptions = Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            LoadingText.VerticalOptions = Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            layout.HorizontalOptions = Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            layout.VerticalOptions = Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            cellImage.HorizontalOptions = Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            cellImage.VerticalOptions = Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;

            if(!hasLoadedAdAtLeastOnce)
            {
                AdView.Content.TranslationY = 5;
                AdView.Content.TranslationX = -20;
                hasLoadedAdAtLeastOnce = true;
            }

            cellImage.WidthRequest = 260;
            cellImage.HeightRequest = 173;
            _ad = (Controls.Ad)AdView.Content;
            View = layout;
```

Comment: If there is no need to scroll list will not scroll. if there is a need and you disable it how your user will be able to scroll?

Comment: Yuri, please read my question. I don't mean to be rude, but your comment is irrelevant. We have a listview, which when you tap on a cell, it will auto scroll to that cell. You say "If there is no need to scroll list will not scroll". That's not true. If someone taps on a cell, then clearly it doesn't need to be scrolled, right? I just don't want it to auto-scroll to the cell that you tapped on.

Comment: I have never seen the case when my list is not going out of screen (or listview dimensions) and it starts scrolling.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying if a user taps on a cell, it will 'center' the cell I guess would be a better word for it. So lets say 3 cells are visible, if you tap on 2, it will essentially scroll to center the 2nd cell. Bad verbiage on my part, sorry.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Recycle List View." I do not see the behavior you describe by default when using a `ListView` with the `CachingStrategy` set to `Recyle` (if that is what you mean by recycle list view). A simple list, on my  end never scrolls when an item is selected. From other similar questions about how to make the `ListView` autoscroll on item tap, it seems your code has to make it auto scroll. Are you working from a sample that perhaps implemented this?

Comment: Nope, that's impossible because I wrote it myself. Did not use any sample code. Not saying you're wrong, but saying it's impossible that I coded it to do that. And yes by `Recycle List View` I do mean a Xamarin Forms ListView set to Recycle.  I've added some code, perhaps it's my layout?